# GmailApp Attachment - attachment.getName() - Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, email-attachments

I have an app that started having an issue about a month ago.
The code parses email attachments in CSV format and then updates a Google Sheet.

This is the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined
> at updateSource(Code:16:48)

Code as follows

```
var label = "Timesheet Data"
  var thread = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();
  var count = thread[0].getMessageCount();
  //Logger.log(count)
  
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var attachment = thread[0].getMessages()[i].getAttachments()[0];
    var fileIndex = csvName.indexOf(attachment.getName());
```

Answer (score 3):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined

most likely means that there is no attachment (and thus no name).

**To avoid this error implement an `if` statement that checks either the email contains attachments before retrieving their names.**

Sample:

```js
var attachments = thread[0].getMessages()[i].getAttachments();
if(attachments.length > 0){
  var attachment = attachments[0];
  var fileIndex = csvName.indexOf(attachment.getName());
  ...
}
```

UPDATE

Sample with logs for debugging:

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var attachments = thread[0].getMessages()[i].getAttachments();
    Logger.log("thread email number  " + i);
    Logger.log("attchment length " +attachments.length);
    if(attachments.length > 0){
      var attachment = attachments[0];
      Logger.log(attachment.getName());
      var fileIndex = csvName.indexOf(attachment.getName());
    }
    else{
     Logger.log("no attachments");
    }
  }
```

Comment: The label holds an email with 4 attachments so that isn't the problem and this has been working well for over 2 years.

Comment: Maybe then the specific email has more than one attachment and some of the attachmenets is corrupt or feautures other problems? Does this problem happen for a very specific email? Try to identify it by logging the message / thread id and have a look at its attachments.

Comment: Sorry, I send 4 emails from SQL to this label and the code strips the attachment in each email. I was looking at the code and getName doesn't seem to be available as an attachment property. My debugging skills suck btw.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your comment correctly - has the issue been solved after you found the attachments that caused you the issue?

Comment: No, the label contains 4 emails, the issue is not fixed.  There is no problem with the attachments and the process to email them has not changed in over 2 years. Problem persists.

Comment: You say there is an email with 4 attachments, but maybe the thread has more than 1 email and not all of the emails have an attachment? Did you try the code snippet I proposed - it should solve the issue. I updated the code with logs that should help you to understand what is happening.

Comment: Well you were correct. Apparently the process doesn't see an empty CSV as qualifying as an attachment. Our ERP had an update that inserted a non numeric entry and the filter for the query was based on an integer.Change it to a literal '80' in the filter the query ran and the CSV files imported into the back end sheet. TY for pointing me in the right direction